# When should I use recursive feature elimination vs genetic algorithms vs simulated annealing?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, feature-selection

What is the best practice for choosing the feature selection algorithm? Should I try all of them and check their performance?

I'd like to know if there are some situations where one is usually better than the other, depending on the problem and the dataset nature.